# Favicon on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, favicon

I've got a problem with my favicon on wordpress, I didn't even figure it out why because it worked on firefox. But let me review the problem. I used two ways to display the favicon on my website. My first approach was to add the favicon on the head with the link tag in this way:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/chick.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/chick.svg">
```

and it didn't work.

Then I tried adding it with the site identity with wordpress, so I uploaded a png file through the wordpress dashboard (customize). But it didn't work too, I mean, the weird thing was that I was able to see my favicon, but only when I was on the dashboard page or for example in my 404 page (and each single-post).

I quitted because I was working on other thing of my website (the favicon worked anyway if I browse my site with firefox).

Anyway today I had to switch my domain name for working reason, the website which I'm building is for a client, and now I've realized that I'm able to display my favicon on chrome, but it's the older one of the domain in which I migrate. Does anyone know why it is happening?

my website address is: chickapea.me .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WordPress Version 4.3 or later:

- Prepare a `favicon.ico` image file which must be square and at least 512
  pixels wide and tall.
- Go to Administration Screen > Appearance > Customize
- Click Site Identify
- Click Select Image at Site Icon section, upload your `favicon.ico` image file and click Select.

You should also upload a copy of your `favicon.ico` file to the main directory of your site.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon for full details.