# Favicon isn't visible

Tags: favicon

I tried to add a favicon (simple #101010 square) to my [website](http://www.dstruning.com/). However, it isn't visible and I have no clue why. Can anybody help me?

I use the following code to embed the favicon in Wordpress.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.dstruning.com/wp-content/themes/dstruning/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.dstruning.com/wp-content/themes/dstruning/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: usually it is recommended to have the favicon at root level

Comment: It works fine. Probably a caching issue on your part. Try refreshing the page with `Shift+F5`

Comment: It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome... refreshed the page multiple times as well as deleted the cache.

Comment: @didi It works in Chrome here

Comment: Mmm, weird. But good to know, seems to be a local issue. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38013283/1983389